# HTMLPurifier allowing blockquote and ins tag with cite

Tags: htmlpurifier

I want the following tags to be allowed in HTMLPurifier.
For example:

```
<ins cite="blog.html"></ins>
<blockquote cite="https://www.google.com/"></blockquote>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional tags and attributes to the allowed list. For example, to add `blockquote` and `ins` tags with the `cite` attribute:

```
 $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
 $def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
 $def->addElement('blockquote', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', ['cite' => 'URI']);
 $def->addElement('ins', 'Inline', 'Flow', 'Common', ['cite' => 'URI']);
 $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Now, when you use this `$purifier` instance to purify HTML, it will allow the `cite` attribute for both `blockquote` and `ins` tags in addition to the default allowed tags and attributes.

**Remember** to customize the allowed elements and attributes carefully to match your specific use case and security requirements. Always validate and sanitize user input to prevent **XSS** attacks and other security vulnerabilities in your application.